# Configuring DNS server on webmin

Tags: domains, dns, webmin

I want to point my domain to my VPS (OS: CentOS7, installed webmin on it) and created a virtual host, then followed http://www.webtop.com.au/blog/how-to-setup-dns-using-webmin-2009052848 instructions to create a DNS zone. also in domain registrars panel, every thing is set to my VPS ip (178.32.211.6).

but after 3 days, I checked intodns.com and saw the DNS server is not responding. I also should mention that if I login to my vps, and get ping to domain, it works! but from outside, it doesn't works.

here is my zone configuration file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17246241/

Comment: Last I looked, Bind by default only responds on the local network or on local host depending. Can you edit the question and include the Bind configuration file? That may help. Not the zone file, the server configuration file. Cheers!!

Comment: Please edit your question and include details of your IP tables, and the virtual host file.

Comment: You were right! the problem was with IP tables! I just opened port 53 and everything was solved.